# Select value dependent on other column value

Tags: sqlite

I want the query to return the distance if the user has opted to show their position. This is what I have:

```
SELECT 
  showpos, 
  CASE distance WHEN showpos=1 THEN distance ELSE "N/A" END 
FROM table
```

I also have a case statement for showpos (1=True/0=False) but this does not have any errors. This is not returning the correct results. How do I make it show distance only when showpos=1 and return "N/A" when showpos=0?

Original data:

[image: original data]

After Query Results:

[image: returned data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT showpos, 
       CASE WHEN showpos = 1 THEN distance ELSE 'N/A' END
FROM mytable
```

or

```
SELECT showpos, 
       CASE showpos WHEN 1 THEN distance ELSE 'N/A' END
FROM mytable
```